# ParseUser using phone number and one time verification code

Tags: parse-platform

Currently, Parse allows to create user based on username and password. This make sense for web world as well few mobile applications.

However, I am looking to implement sms based authentication what whatsapp and recently twitter did. The idea is you ask user his phone number and then send a one time verification code (random 6 digit code) via SMS to that phone number. You then ask user to enter that verification code. If the code match, user is considered as signed in and in which case we want to use phone number as the primary id (or username).

However, if the user uninstall the app and re-install and tries to login with that phone number, app will again re-send a one time verification code which would be different than the original one time verification code.

Thoughts? Note that we cannot associate a fixed one time verification code with a phone number as it posses security risk.

Comment: One way I can think this can be done using existing Parse infrastructure is: Once user enters phone number, query parse user object to see if there is a user with a property "phone" as the number entered. If yes, then you got the user. If not, create an anonymous user and associate phone property as that phone. Now, once user puts the right verification code, you simply let him in.

Answer (score 1):

But today on Parse it is mandatory to provide at least a username and a password. Which not fit with the process of signup/login only with phone numbers. Of course we could generate a random username and password that would never be used again... But that is not very efficient. 
I would like to know if the Parse team is going to address this new behavior (using only phone number) that more and more people are using for their apps.

Thanks!

Comment: One other way this can be done is - use phone number as the username and password as always a constant say "abcd" for all the users. After user went through phone number validation, we can either login that user if he/she exists or signup if this is the first time system sees this phone number.